# Adobe Acrobat folder level scripts

Tags: javascript, automation, pdf, adobe

I am trying to find ínformation on how and where to write folder level scripts for Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Photoshop. This is what I found from Adobe:
https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/folder_level_scripts
None of the info on this page works for me since it is outdated. Anyone have any tips? I have contacted Adobe Support but they refer me to "a developer"

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you are attempting to write Acrobat JavaScript scripts, you will need the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, downloadable from the [Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html). There you will find the location for application-level scripts.

Comment: The information there is old and outdated :-(

Comment: As "old and outdated" as the Acrobat DC SDK can be…

Comment: Sorry my fault, I will dl this today!

Comment: No problem… BTW, sorry, I did forget the smiley in my last comment. :)